# Obtener un valor de un objeto multidimensional PHP Symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony3

Hola soy principiante y quiero obtener el valor que se encuentra en el siguiente objeto específicamente en: `[id:AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost:private] => 1` y almacenarlo en una variable.

La primera parte es el resultado del `print_r` y la segunda parte es el código, gracias

```
 AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost Object
    (
        [id:AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost:private] => 1
        [title:AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost:private] => Primera entrada de Blog
        [content:AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost:private] => Lorem Ipsum
        [createdAt:AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost:private] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2011-01-01 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
            )

    )


public function showAction($id)
{
    $blogentry = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:BlogPost')
        ->find($id);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($blogentry);
    echo "</pre>";


    if (!$blogentry) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '. $blogentry
        );
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:default:show.html.twig', array(
        'blogentry' => $blogentry
    ));
}
```

Comment: Según veo el id es accesible mediante el método `getId()` como dice acá: https://github.com/codereviewvideos/api.symfony-3.crud/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Entity/BlogPost.php

Comment: hice la prueba y funciona bien

Comment: ¿Significa que pudiste acceder al valor del id con `getId()`?

Comment: Así es muchas gracias

Comment: Excelente, en ese caso, escribí la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según veo el `id` es accesible mediante el método `getId()`:

```
/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

[Fuente](https://github.com/codereviewvideos/api.symfony-3.crud/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Entity/BlogPost.php)